# Radio selector with different controls HTML Jquery Mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

How can I create html to make a radio selection of different controls other than labels? I want to select either a dropdown or a group of text inputs.

I am looking for a way to add a radio button in front of the dropdown and a radio button in front of the text inputs. So I can tell if the user wants to enter data via the dropdown or enter data via the text boxes

I am not sure how I could setup the markup for this?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your goal, it's not clear. What do you want to happen or see when the Radio Check is selected?

Comment: Simply a way to add a radio button in front of the dropdown and a radio button in front of the text inputs. So I can tell if the user wants to enter data via the dropdown or enter data via the text boxes

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pQfDm/

Layout Grids can help you here:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Radio Selectors</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h2>Header Bar</h2>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <form>
                    <div class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 15%; padding-right: 10px">
                            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" />
                                <label for="radio-choice-1" data-iconpos="notext">Choice 1</label>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b" style="width: 85%">
                            <input type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 15%; padding-right: 10px">
                            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" />
                                <label for="radio-choice-1" data-iconpos="notext">Choice 1</label>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b" style="width: 85%">
                            <select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-0" data-theme="b">
                                <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
                                <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
                                <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
                                <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is possible to modify this to only select one radio button or the other. Right now you are able to select both

Comment: Possibly using the `fieldset` to contain all the items. I didn't test it. Can do it via JQuery. Bind a function that unchecks the radios and then only allows `$(this)` to remain selected.

Comment: Yes, you can by moving the `fieldset` yet it has poor results: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pQfDm/4/ Will try and show you an example that makes it cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the other example I had mentioned: http://jsfiddle.net/pQfDm/5/

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Radio Selectors</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h2>Header Bar</h2>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <form>
                    <div class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 15%; padding-right: 10px">
                            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" />
                                <label for="radio-choice-1" data-iconpos="notext">Choice 1</label>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b" style="width: 85%">
                            <input type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 15%; padding-right: 10px">
                            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" />
                                <label for="radio-choice-2" data-iconpos="notext">Choice 2</label>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b" style="width: 85%">
                            <select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-0" data-theme="b">
                                <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
                                <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
                                <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
                                <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='radio-choice']").click(function() {
        $("input[name='radio-choice']").each(function() {
            $(this).removeAttr("checked");
        });
        $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
        $("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio("refresh");
    });
});
```

You could add to the JQuery to Enable/Disable elements when their Radio is Checked/Unchecked.